# Как хранить в app.config величины типа TimeSpan

Tags: c#

Можно ли как-то удобно хранить в app.config значения типа TimeSpan? Чтобы не задавать их в секундах:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Task1Name:PollingInterval" value="300" />
</appSettings>
```

Сейчас храню число секунд и не нравится лишняя работа по преобразованию:

```
int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Task1Name:PollingInterval"], out var pollingInterval);
if (pollingInterval == 0)
    pollingInterval = 1000;

return new IStartStopSevice[]
{
    new MyTask1(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(pollingInterval)),
};
```

Возможно, в новых версиях языка есть какой-то дополнительный синтаксический сахарок, чтобы сократить число строк?

Про вариант

```
new MyTask1(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(pollingInterval == 0 ? 1000 : pollingInterval)),
```

знаю.

Comment: Как TimeSpan: `00:00:00`

Comment: Сократить 5 строк кода? :)

Comment: А если просто через Properties - Settings добавить?

Comment: Это смотрели: https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/base/level4/4_5.php ?